# Equality VS equity

Tags: word-choice, difference

Is my following understanding accurate?

Both words can mean “a situation in which everyone is treated equally”. They are interchangeable in the following cases:

*1,A society should run on the principles of equity/equality and justice.*

*2,In making these decisions we should be governed by the principle of equity/equality.*

However, equity is a formal and rarer word, and has other meanings, so it is slightly better to use equality in the above cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While those two words are often used interchangeably, they don't actually mean exactly the same thing. The definition you gave:

> a situation in which everyone is treated equally

only really applies to "equality".

The word "equity" on the other hand refers to treating everyone according to their needs.

Treating everyone equally, i.e giving them the same benefits, doesn't imply an equitable, or fair result, because different people may have different handicaps that require them to get proportionally more benefits.

Here's a classic example of an image that's used to illustrate this point:

[image]

As can be seen in the left hand image, everyone is being treated equally, i.e. they are all given the same height box to stand on. However, that results in a situation that is not equitable. In the right hand image, they are given different boxes of different heights, and a ramp, and that scenario leads to an equitable situation where they all get the same view of the game.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot believe dictionaries leave out this important information. So which is a better word choice in my two sentences in the post? Or due to a lack of adequate context, both sound equally good.

Comment: @joy2020 It depends on which meaning you want to convey. In the first sentence, I prefer equity, but I think using *both* is fine as well. In the second sentence, it depends on the context, so I can't really say which one you should use.

Comment: It seems like this might be a context specific jargon usage rather than conventional usage of the words "equality" and "equity".  In normal usage I would consider both situations to be covered by both words and I would not expect to be understood the way you suggest without explaining that jargon.

Comment: @smithkm Well, the words mean different things. It's true that in many contexts, people don't bother with (or don't know) the distinction and so it doesn't matter to them (or their audience) which one they use. I personally think that people should use those words appropriately, especially because people think *equality* means *fairness* which is not true.

Comment: +1 I wouldn't call this jargon at all. Jargon is diction used by a particular profession, which I believe is not the case here. This distinction exists in a lot of contexts.

Comment: @joy2020 How far did you look when you looked up those two words in dictionaries? [Merriam Webster: Sameness vs. Fairness](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/equality-vs-equity-difference)

Comment: @Eddie Kal Thanks. The link you provided is englightening, and it leads me to differentiate [gender equity/equality](https://www.pipelineequity.com/voices-for-equity/gender-equity-vs-gender-equality/). This post highlights one aspect of the difference, though.

Answer (score 1):

### Equality VS equity Both words can mean “a situation in which everyone is treated equally”. They are interchangeable in the following cases:

**A society should run on the principles of equity/equality and justice.**

Q. However, equity is a formal and rarer word, and has other meanings, so it is slightly better to use equality in the above cases.

**I would suggest you cannot use equity in this sentence**

---

I would also suggest that when you analyse the sentence it does not mean what you wish to imply.

A society should run on the principles of equity/equality and justice. In my opinion you should use the following sentence.

We should live in a **society based on equality and social justice**

---

My reasons

**A society** should run on the .......

As far as I am aware you cannot directly control a society. A society is usually Governed (You may drive a car or vehicle but you  cannot drive traffic).

**should run on**? what like a car runs on petrol? or do you mean should be run on? However back to my previous point. Is run the correct word? should it not be Governed?

**equity/equality and justice.**

justice = fairness.... equity = fairness. **Note** If you take the other meaning for Justice, law, this is not appropriate as even Hitler & Stalin had Laws but we would not necessary call them just.

Therefore we should just say equality or **equality and social justice**. (There is also a second reason for not using equity which is shown in relation to your second sentence).

### Equality VS equity Both words can **mean “a situation in which everyone is treated equally**”. They are interchangeable in the following cases:

**In making these decisions we should be governed by the principle of equity/equality.**

Q. However, equity is a formal and rarer word, and has other meanings, so it is slightly better to use equality in the above cases.

I would suggest you cannot use equity in this sentence, because when you use equity in the sentence it does not mean what you wish to imply.

In my opinion the sentence should be

**In making these decisions we should be governed by the principles of equality**

---

My reasons

**equity** noun (FAIRNESS) the situation in which everyone is treated fairly and equally:

so if we replace Equity in the sentence, with the definition, does this read correctly

*"by the principle of the situation in which everyone is treated fairly and equally"* **Does this sentence make any sense?**

**equality** noun the right of different groups of people to have a similar social position and receive the same treatment:

Now replace equality, does it read correctly?

**be governed by the principle of the right of different groups of people to have a similar social position and receive the same treatment:**

---

All ref CED [**Cambridge English Dictionary**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/equity)

**equity** noun **(FAIRNESS)** **the situation** in which everyone is treated fairly and equally:

**equality** noun the **right of different groups** of people to have a similar social position and receive the same treatment:

**society** noun **(PEOPLE)** a large group of people who live together in an organized way, making decisions about how to do things and sharing the work that needs to be done. All the people in a country, or in several similar countries, can be referred to as a society:

**govern** verb **to control** and be responsible for the public business of a country, state, city, or other organized group:

**justice** noun **fairness** in the way people are dealt with:

**justice** noun **(LAW)** the system of laws in a country that judges and punishes people: